# Finding a delta for a given limit

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Given this limit: $\lim_{x->-1} \frac{\sqrt{x+5}-2}{x+1}=\frac{1}{4}$
Find a $\delta > 0 $ such that for $ |x-(-1)| < \delta $ exists:

$|\frac{\sqrt{x+5}-2}{x+1}-L|<\frac{1}{1000}$

I started with:

$|\frac{\sqrt{x+5}-2}{x+1}-\frac{1}{4} | < \epsilon$

 which can be simplified like this: 
 $$ |\frac{(\sqrt{x+5}-2)(\sqrt{x+5}+2)}{(x+1)(\sqrt{x+5}+2)}-\frac{1}{4} | <\epsilon $$
$$ |\frac{x+1}{(x+1)(\sqrt{x+5}+2)}| < \epsilon $$
$$ |\frac{1}{(\sqrt{x+5}+2)}| < \epsilon$$ 

And got stuck again...I thought I should used the $x+1$ because I already know that $|x+1|<\delta$ but it disappeared with the calculation.. any suggestions?

Comment: Are the symbols =>  and $\geq$ the same?

Comment: No, I edited to be more clear.

Comment: So they were "$=$", right?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to show how I simplified the equation

Comment: it's definitely not clear ! what are the expressions at the end of your post ? equality ? inequality ?

Comment: is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\left|\dfrac{\sqrt{x+5}-2}{x+1}-\dfrac{1}{4}\right|&=\left|\dfrac{2-\sqrt{x+5}}{4(2+\sqrt{x+5})}\right|\\
&=\left|\dfrac{2-\sqrt{x+5}}{4(2+\sqrt{x+5})}\cdot\dfrac{2+\sqrt{x+5}}{2+\sqrt{x+5}}\right|\\
&=\left|\dfrac{-x-1}{4(2+\sqrt{x+5})^2}\right|\\
&=\dfrac{|x+1|}{4(2+\sqrt{x+5})^2}
\end{align}

Note that $\dfrac{|x+1|}{4(2+\sqrt{x+5})^2}\leq\dfrac{|x+1|}{16}$ and $$\left|\dfrac{\sqrt{x+5}-2}{x+1}-\dfrac{1}{4}\right|=\dfrac{|x+1|}{4(2+\sqrt{x+5})^2}\leq\dfrac{|x+1|}{16}<\varepsilon\Rightarrow|x+1|<16\varepsilon$$

So we choose $\delta=16\varepsilon$ and we are done.